# Https redirect in download file with curl

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have a problem with curl. I try to download file from another server. Script download only this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Site</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ('https:' !== location.protocol) location.replace(location.toString().replace(location.protocol, 'https:'));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/includes.js"></script>
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="xml/search.xml"/>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!location.hash || '_=_' == location.hash) location.replace('/#' + location.pathname + location.search);
</script>
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;?nojs" />
    <a href="?nojs">HTML only version</a>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

I think, that it crach on https:// redirect.

My CURL script:

```
$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
    CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // return headers 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
    CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings 
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 1,     //put this also
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false  // this also
); 

$ch = curl_init(str_replace('https://', 'http://', $workerLocation)); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$out = fopen($fileLocation, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);

$content    = curl_exec($ch); 
fclose($out);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Remove (comment) `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` option from options array

Comment: Hi, I change it, but I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

JS script in the html you provided do replacing `http` protocol with `https`. Your php script should mimic this operation. But it doesn't so since you've confused the order of parameters in `str_replace` call. `str_replace('https://', 'http://', $workerLocation)` is intended to replace 'https://' with 'http://'. But you need to do the reverse operation.

So you have to fix the order of parameters:

```
$ch = curl_init(str_replace('http://', 'https://', $workerLocation));
```

Comment: I dont have problem on entry page, but after first redirect. I remote str_replace, but problem persist.